# I have used the code rankx(All('Advisor Data'),[Score],,DESC,Dense) to rank my data basis score which is a measure

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUpqO.jpg)

i want to rank score in my table.I am getting first rank as 11 and second rand as 21,24,32 and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
measure_score = sum('Advisor Data'[score])

measure_rankx = rankx(All('Advisor Data'), [measure_score],, DESC, Dense)
```

Comment: My data has a month coloumn and i want to rank the score (which is the avg of two months), how do i get the RankX function ignore the date.

Comment: Share the screen shots of data table and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Rank = rankx('Advisor Data',[Score],[Score],DESC)

you don't need calculate measure of score, just use column score is fine.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BayQT.png)

Comment: This is giving me rank as random numbers.

Comment: will you show me file or screenshot?

Comment: See the screen shot i have uploaded in my query

Comment: My data has a month column and i want to rank the score (which is the avg of two months), how do i get the RankX function ignore the date.